# How to use component templates when creating a Nuxt app?

Tags: html, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to create a dynamic header using Vue in a Nuxt application. However, the problem is two-fold:

1) I cannot get the template in the original DOM to be filled in with the template in the external file, which I was able to do by making the whole thing in .html files. I normally would use new Vue(el:...) for this, however even after including the latest version in the `<head>`, I cannot make that solution work.

2) I cannot get the proper data to display. When trying to insert the text, I can either get the index that I pass in, or it will error out.

My component that I am trying to pass in:

```html
    <template id="comp-dem-template">
        <header-component>
            <!-- Should call the function in "data" then replace the title. Instead has error about how it cannot search with 'in' -->
            <span slot="pagetitle">
                {{title}}
            </span>
        </header-component>
    </template>

<script>
module.exports = {
    el: '#header-component',
    template: '<h1><slot name="pagetitle">Page Title Fallback</slot></h1>',
    props: ['index'],
    data: function () {
        if (this.index == 0){
            title: 'Index';
        }
        else if (this.index == 1){
            title: 'Events';
        }
        else if (this.index == 2){
            title: 'Policy';
        }
        else if (this.index == 3){
            title: 'Frequently Asked Questions';
        }
        else if (this.index == 4){
            title: 'Reservations';
        }
        else if (this.index == 5){
            title: 'View Reservations';
        }
        else {
            title: 'Make a Reservation';
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

And the place I am trying to pass it in to:

```html
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<template>
  <div class="container">
      <logo />
<!-- This should be replaced with <h1><span>(name)</span></h1> according to my normal HTML version, however it doesn't here -->
      <headercomponent index="0" />
      <navbar/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Logo from '~/components/Logo.vue'
import headercomponent from '~/components/header-component.vue'
import navbar from '~/components/nav-bar.vue'
export default {
  components: {
    Logo,
    headercomponent,
    navbar
  }
}
// Where I would normally try to insert it. However, even using the newest vue in the head won't let me do this ('Vue is not defined')
new Vue({ el: '#comp-dem-template' })
</script>
```

Comment: You're not defining the SFC correctly, and you don't need to instantiate Vue in a *Nuxt* app. I recommend carefully reading through the Vue and Nuxt docs to familiarize yourself with the fundamentals. If you'd rather dive in head first, try creating a [sample Nuxt app](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/installation#using-code-create-nuxt-app-code-), and following the conventions found in the generated project (which would likely help you with your question here).

Answer (score 0):

Your component has a lot of garbage, let's clean a little,

```
<template>
  <span class="header-link">
    {{ title }}
  </span>
</template>

<script>
  module.exports = {
   name: 'header-component',
   props: ['title']
  }
</script>

<style>
  .header-link {
  }
</style>
```

You can call them using:

```
<header-component title="some text" />
```

in this way you keep the code clear and simple, but if you absolutely need send a index value here the component:

```
<template>
  <span class="header-link">
    {{ title }}
  </span>
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
  name: 'header-component',
  props: ['index'],
  data: function() {
    return {
      title: ''
  }
},


mounted: function() {
    if (this.index === 0) {
      this.title = 'Index'
    } else if (this.index === 1) {
      this.title = 'Events'
    } else if (this.index === 2) {
      this.title = 'Policy'
    } else if (this.index === 3) {
      this.title = 'Frequently Asked Questions'
    } else if (this.index === 4) {
      this.title = 'Reservations'
    } else if (this.index === 5) {
      this.title = 'View Reservations'
    } else {
      this.title = 'Make a Reservation'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.header-link {
}
</style>
```

use them like your example

```
<headercomponent index="0" />
```

the important part is understand the vue lifecycle, https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks, so Props not exist directly in data, but exist in mounted.